# How to Animate a UIImage out of the Screen in Swift

Tags: animation, uiimage, xcode10, swift4.2

i have searched around the web but nothing could answer my question.

I am trying to animate an UIImageview out of the Screen, set the alpha of it to 0, reset its position and reset the alpha to 1 again. 
I can't seem to get the right position where to animate the Image to.

I have set up a gesturerecognizer to drag the image around and when the center of the image is above a certain point, i want to animate it out of screen.

This is the Regocnizercode :

```
@objc func imageDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    //Current Point where the label is dragged
    let draggedLabelPoint = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: view)
    //Updating the center of the label : viewcenter +/- currentpoint
    matchImageView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width/2 + draggedLabelPoint.x, y: view.bounds.height/2 + draggedLabelPoint.y)

    let xFromCenter = view.bounds.width/2 - matchImageView.center.x
    var rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: xFromCenter / -500)
    let scale = min(100/abs(xFromCenter),1)
    var scaledAndRotated = rotation.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)

    //Transforming the Item respective to the distance from center
    matchImageView.transform = scaledAndRotated

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended {
        if matchImageView.center.x < (view.bounds.width/2 - 100) {
            animateImageToSide(target: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width - 200, y: matchImageView.center.y))
            matchImageView.alpha = 0
        }

        if matchImageView.center.x > (view.bounds.width/2 + 100) {
            animateImageToSide(target: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width + 200, y: matchImageView.center.y))
            matchImageView.alpha = 0
        }

        //Reset the scaling variables and recentering the Item after swipe
        rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)
        scaledAndRotated = rotation.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 1)
        matchImageView.transform = scaledAndRotated
        matchImageView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width/2, y: view.bounds.height/2)

    }
}
```

I am sorry if the resetting part is irrelevant for you, but im not sure if this could cause this behavior.

And this is my current Animationmethod :

```
func animateImageToSide(target:CGPoint){
    UIImageView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {self.matchImageView.center = target}) { (success: Bool) in
        self.updateImage()
        self.fadeInImage()//This is where i set the alpha back to 1
    }
}
```

I am not sure if a CGPoint is what i need to use.

The current behavoir of the image is very weird. Most of the time it snaps to a specific place, regardless of the targetposition. Maybe my attempt on this is entirely wrong.

Thanks for your help !